# high dpi chrome 36 on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, high-dpi

I have this weird issue with chrome. When I launch it in desktop mode, everything is blurry. However when I go to its settings and relaunch in windows 8 mode, everything is super clear and crisp.

I have a QHD+ screen and firefox is so far the only browser which works out of the box, but I want to use chrome. However I don't want to use it in windows 8 mode (metro crap). I've scoured the internet for answers but the registry hack doesn't seem to work anymore.

Why is it that I **have** to launch chrome in windows 8 mode to get hidpi support?

Note: the chrome://flags page says that high dpi is not available on my platform.. what?

Comment: In your Settings->Advanced settings is Page Zoom = 100%?

Comment: Chrome 37 seems to solve the issue. It's in beta but works fine